# how to add prefix in every 2nd delimeted field in every record in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with following records which is comma delimited:

```
143849998,+4564656
6345353,000345345
754656,0345345
64555546,3453452345
```

The requirement is to add a certain prefix to every 2nd field in every record. The prefix is different in different conditions. The logic is :

1. If the second field starts with "+", then leave it as it is.
2. If the second field starts with "0" (Any number of zeroes, does not matter), replace all zeroes with "+".
3. If any other condition prefix "+234".

The output should be something like this:

```
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

How can I achieve this using AWK? I am able to perform the last condition, the first condition is straight forward, but I am failing when I am trying to club all the conditions in one awk command.

Answer (score 4):

this line should do

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '$2!~/^\+/{if(!sub(/^0+/,"+",$2))$2="+234"$2}7' file 
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

or it could be this too:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '$2!~/^\+/&&!sub(/^0+/,"+",$2){$2="+234"$2}7' file
```

Comment: I like the way of using the result of sub() as boolean!

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's|,\([1-9]\)|,+234\1|; s|,0\+|,+|' file
```

Synonymously in `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub(/,([1-9])/, ",+234\1"); sub(/,0+/, ",+") } 1' file
```

Output:

```
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1",+"($2~/^[+0]/?"":234)$2+0}' file
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

Adding 0 to $2 strips off any leading zeros and/or plus sign since it's doing an arithmetic operation on it and so the natural result will not have a sign or leading zeros.

Note that this approach will convert `+03` to `+3` and `-3` to `+-3` so if those can occur in your input and that's not the desired behavior, update your question to show those cases in the sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2~/^0/{sub(/^0+/, "+", $2);} !($2~/^\+/){$2="+234" $2}1' file
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

OR using non-regex based checks:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} substr($2,1,1)=="0"{sub(/^0+/, "+", $2);}
        substr($2,1,1)!="+"{$2="+234" $2}1' file
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

Comment: I really need to learn that I can match the fields individually.

Comment: Yes that is the advantage of using awk, to be able to operate on row, column basis.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is as it is:

```
 awk -F",|,[0]+" '/,\+/{ print $0;next } /,0/ {print $1",+"$2; next} {print $1",+234"$2} ' file
```

gives

```
143849998,+4564656
6345353,+345345
754656,+345345
64555546,+2343453452345
```

It works as follows:

either `,` or `,000` (with an arbitrary number of 0s) is a field separator. Then we have the three rules:

1. match `,+` (literally) -> print the line, go to next line
2. match `,0` -> split the line (awk removes all the , and 0s for us), print separated, go to next line
3. if no match until now, prefix the second with "+234"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following awk script:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{sub(/^0+/, "+", $2)}!($2~/[0+]/){$2="+234"$2}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/,+/b;/,00*/s//,+/;t;s/,/&+234/' file
```

As per spec.